# How to write if statement for when a specified option is selected in select tag in JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I am wanting to have an `if` statement within a form, that will not allow the form to send if the disabled select (placeholder) is selected. However, I am not sure how to do this?

My attempt:

```js
if ($("option:selected") == $('#dis')) {
  error_last_name = 'Last Name is required';
  
  $('#error_last_name').text(error_last_name);
  $('#Event_Name').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Privilege: </label>
  
  <select name="Privilege" id="Privilege" class="dialogin">
    <option id="dis" disabled selected>Select a Privilege:</option>
    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="privileged">Privileged</option>
  </select>
  
  <span id="error_last_name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this does not do anything. Any help is appreciated :) The variable `error_last_name` has been created before.

Answer (score 1):

Add a value tag in the option. Use the below line to get value selected option. I have used the select box change event to show message.

```
var getVal = $("#Privilege option:selected").val();
```

```js
$("#Privilege").change(function(){
  var getVal = $("#Privilege option:selected").val();

  if (getVal == "") {
    alert("empty");
    // your code
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Privilege: </label>
  
  <select name="Privilege" id="Privilege" class="dialogin">
    <option value="" id="dis"  selected>Select a Privilege:</option>
    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="privileged">Privileged</option>
  </select>
  
  <span id="error_last_name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check jQuery object equality with `==`. You have two possibilities here:

- By using [`jQuery#is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) (`if ($("option:selected")is($('#dis')))`)
- By comparing their value (`if ($("option:selected").val() === $('#dis').val())`)

I used the second one for the snippet below:

```js
if ($("option:selected").val() === $('#dis').val()) {
  error_last_name = 'Last Name is required';

  $('#error_last_name').text(error_last_name);
  $('#Event_Name').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Privilege: </label>
  
  <select name="Privilege" id="Privilege" class="dialogin">
    <option id="dis" disabled selected>Select a Privilege:</option>
    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="privileged">Privileged</option>
  </select>
  
  <span id="error_last_name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the whole element, the better way will be compare the value selected:

```
if ($("option:selected").val() === $('#dis').val())

<option value="default" id="dis" disabled selected>Select a Privilege:</option>
```

Or if you want to compare the element:

```
if ($("option:selected")[0] === $('#dis')[0])
```